# Table: add a column inside a column

Tags: tables

I need to add one more column to the 4th column and 5th column so that I can put rmse train and rmse validation. Any hint?

[image]

This is my actual code:

```
 \begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}

    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
        \hline
         &  & & \textbf{Movielens 100K} &\textbf{Movielens 1M   }  \\
         $\lambda$ & $\gamma$ & Epochs & rmse & rmse  \\ 
        \hline
        0.01 & 0.006 & 35 & 0.9385 & \\ \hline
        0.01 & 0.003 & 34 &  & 0.9078 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

My failed attempt:

```
    \begin{table}
\begin{center}

    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}  % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
        \hline
        &  & & \textbf{Movielens 100K   } &\textbf{Movielens 1M }  \\
        $\lambda$ & $\gamma$ & Epochs & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ rmse }& rmse  \\ 
        \hline
        0.01 & 0.006 & 35 & 0.9385 & \\ \hline
        0.01 & 0.003 & 34 &  & 0.9078 \\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: you need to declare two more column, i.e.:  `\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|} }` and for column  header use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{ ....}`.

Comment: I just updated my post. I cannot get it right :(

Comment: it will be helpful if you would provide complete document, not only table code fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is to long for the comment .... Ii suspect that you looking for something like this

[image]

but I'm not sure. Please explain in comparison to above table, how should looks your table. MWE for above table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}  % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
   \hline
            &   &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Movielens 100K}}
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Movielens 1M }}  \\
    \cline{4-7}
$\lambda$   & $\gamma$  & Epochs&  rmse     &       & rmse  &   \\
        \hline
0.01        & 0.006     & 35    & 0.9385    &       &       &   \\
    \hline
0.01        & 0.003     & 34    &           & 0.9078&       &   \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! Check my post, I have edited it with your code!